# Can I use a template-part inside a WP Query?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, nested-loops, custom-post-type

I am building my custom WP theme, that consists of multiple custom post types. One of the CPT is artists and the others are music labels:

CPT#1: Artists
CPT#2: Music Label called 'Triple Cash'
CPT#3: Music Label called 'Bloom'
CPT#4: Music Label called 'Genuine'
CPT#5: Music Label called 'Revma'

In the artists archive page, I have managed to create relationships between the artists and the music labels. I am using the following code to display all albums where the artist is involved:

```
$relatedAlbums = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => array('triple','bloom', 'genuine', 'revma'),
    'meta_key' => 'release_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
        'meta_query' => array(
         array(
             'key' => 'related_artists',
             'compare' => 'LIKE',
             'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"'
             )
           )
         ));
```

As more music labels might be added in the future, I was thinking if there is a way to create something like a global variable where I can enter all music label and use that within the post_type array.

I have tried to solve it using template-parts:

```
$relatedAlbums = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        get_template_part('template-parts/labels'),
    'meta_key' => 'release_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
        'meta_query' => array(
         array(
             'key' => 'related_artists',
             'compare' => 'LIKE',
             'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"'
             )
           )
         ));
```

where the labels.php looks like this:

'post_type' => array('triple', 'bloom')

But that didn't work.

Do I need any more code in the labels.php?

Is there any other way to define any global variable for certain CPT, in my case for all music labels?

Comment: So you created one separate custom post _type_ per label? That makes little sense, you should have _one_ custom post type for your labels.

Comment: @CBroe yes, each label has its own custom post type.

Comment: Why? That makes little sense. You should have _one_ post _type_ for this, and then multiple posts _of_ that type, that represent your different labels.

Comment: In my case, a post of a label is called 'album'. So, when you are on a label archive page, you see all albums that have been released under that label. An artist may participate in album that has been released under label A, and an album released under label C

Comment: Your albums should be their own custom post type. And then be connected with a label it was published on, and the artist that recorded it.

Comment: Whether your labels need to be a custom post type, depends on how much extra data you actually want to store for them. If you don't need much more than the name - then they might as well be just a category/taxonomy.

Comment: I wanted to have more flexibility with the labels, that's why I decided to have them as custom post types

Comment: Fair enough, but "label" should still be _one_ custom post type then. And the individual labels are posts of that type then.